# My effect's doesn't work normally When I Resize

Tags: jquery, css, resize

I give some effect in different resolution with css media queries and jquery. İf I reload in any resoluation it's not problem. But It isn't normally while I resize the screen. I know, I haven't good english but if you try, I hope you can understand. Also I try (window).resize but that's not solve my problem. Thank you. Also the problem is in the opening section (About me).

Demo : [You can try here](http://ardazaman.com/deneme2/)

Code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){


        var width = $(window).width()+17;

        if(width>=1366){
            $('#pp img:eq(0)').animate({
            'right':'0'
        },2000);

            $('#yazi').animate({
                'left':'10%'
            },2000);
        }

        if((width>=601) && (width<=1365)){
            $('#pp img:eq(1)').animate({
                'margin-top':'0'
            },1000);

            $('#yazi').animate({
                'left':'25%'
            },1000);
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try This:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  foo();

  $(window).resize(foo);      
});


function foo(){
   var width = $(window).width()+17;

    if(width>=1366){
        $('#pp img:eq(0)').animate({
        'right':'0'
    },2000);

        $('#yazi').animate({
            'left':'10%'
        },2000);
    }

    if((width>=601) && (width<=1365)){
        $('#pp img:eq(1)').animate({
            'margin-top':'0'
        },1000);

        $('#yazi').animate({
            'left':'25%'
        },1000);
    }
}
```